# How to provide full width in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, user-interface

i have a layout file which contains 6 text views and one image view. the view looks like this

```
ABC    |    DEF
HIJ    |    KLM
NOP    |    QRS
```

This should be a part of horizontal scroll view in a layout. The above view should cover full width of screen, if i swipe then only next view will come. else to user only the above layout should be visible.

I have designed the layout but i'm not getting the desired output.at a time i'm able to see 3 to 4 views of above are getting overlapped,

Here is my layout which looks like above view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EventCode1"
    android:text="Event Code 1"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EventText1"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="Event Text 1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EventCode1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/EventDate1"
    android:text="Event Date 1"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EventText1"/>

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/divider"
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    />

 <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EventCode2"
    android:text="Event Code 2"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EventText2"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="Event Text 2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EventCode2"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EventText2"
    android:id="@+id/EventDate2"
    android:text="Event Date 2"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:layout="@+id/EventDate2"/>


   </RelativeLayout>
```

I will inflate the above layout into a horizontal scrollview which contains liner layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<View
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                   android:background="@drawable/shade"/>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/EventsButton"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/URL"
       android:text="Events Around" />
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/eventlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
   </LinearLayout>
```

here is the code to inflate the custom view and put into horizontal liner layout,

If i have 10 events, ill add it like this. it may very at runtime

```
for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++)
        {


         LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();


        View view = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.greventslayout,null);

        mEventsLayout.addView(view);
        }
```

Update::

After adding the below code i'm getting UI like this.

[image]

Comment: You have added `android:layout_below="@+id/EventCode1"` which forces your EventText1 element to appear just below EventCode1 element.Remove `android:layout_below="@+id/EventCode1"' and this element will appear to center as vertical

Comment: Hi i need 3 text to appear one below another and then a separator after that again i need 3 text to come one below another. i need my custom view to cover full width irrespective of text size. if user swipes from right to left then only new view should come

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".45"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".10"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".45"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the answer, i tried your code, unfortunately the divider image was failing so i removed and added my custom divider. In my case the divider comes fine but "medium text" text is coming in 2 lines and i'm able to see total 2 sets of above layout in a view. i.e in total i'm seeing 12 entries but i need only 6  why? can you please help..

Comment: one moment dude, i will upload. thanks lot for ur support we are closer to answer..

Comment: Hi, i have uploaded the image, can u pls check it

Comment: i think you are adding the relative layout twice, that shrinks the width

Comment: actually i m inflating this view and placing it into horizontal scroll view where in linearlayout sits. i have posted that code too..

Comment: i have removed these stuffs, " android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"" as its not recognizing in my pc

Comment: any luck dude? any hint u got?

Comment: i will post it.. if i get upto it.. !